# Linq to Sql One to many relationship string.join

Tags: c#, json, linq

For a single book in have multiple authors.I want to fetch the values in json format
I get json as

```
"AuthorName":"{ AuthorName = Author1 },{ AuthorName =Author2  }",
```

But I need to get it in

```
"AuthorName":Author1,Author2
```

format.Can I achieve that? here is my query

```
var jsonData = from w in bookData
                           join b in barcodes on w.Id equals b.BookId
                           select new 
                           {
                           w.AccessionNo,
                           AuthorName=string.Join(",", from a in bookAuthor
                                          where a.BookShelfId == w.Id
                                          select new {
                                           a.Authors.AuthorName
                           }),
                        w.BookInfoId,                               
                           };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting a string instead of an anonymous object, like this:

```
var jsonData = from w in bookData
                       join b in barcodes on w.Id equals b.BookId
                       select new 
                       {
                       w.AccessionNo,
                       AuthorName=string.Join(",", from a in bookAuthor
                                      where a.BookShelfId == w.Id
                                      select a.Authors.AuthorName
                       ),
                    w.BookInfoId,                               
                       };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: wow, that works.Thanks.Could not think logically.Now I understand.Will accept in few moment